# angularjs promise with bind function

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller which calls the api.

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function(){

    var promise = userService.getPromise();

    promise.then(function(user){
        if(user.error){
            //handle error
        } else {
            //perform other task
        }
    }.bind(this));

};
```

but I am not able to understand that what does this bind function do.

Comment: Seems like more code is needed to be sure why that's there. `bind(this)` sets the context of the function it is called on, so if `this` is used inside that function, it will refer to `this` that was passed to `bind`. Perhaps there is some code inside of that function that would call `this` and `this` needs to be set correctly. It's all a bit awkward. There's probably a better way to do whatever is trying to be done there.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

so in your case when promise is resolved your callback function will have `this` set to your controller.

Comment: Might want to also add that since `this` is actually not used in the function that `bind` is not actually required in this case.

Comment: @WayneEllery Yes your right. But his question is regarding use of bind() function!!